# Quick Reference Guide to Various NoSQL Databases

Tags: mongodb, redis, riak, membase, nosql

I'm looking for one place that summarizes the main properties of the NoSQL databases that I keep seeing referenced - in particular, MongoDB, Riak, Redis, Memcached, Membase, and Cassandra. Types of queries, acid, architecture for/properties of scaling, etc. All in memory, overflow to disk, backup on disk, or mainly only indexes in memory?

Comment: This is the first google response: http://nosql-database.org/links.html.  What more do you need?  This is the second: http://java.dzone.com/news/nosql-graph-database-feature.

Comment: Please search for dupes before asking. THis has been asked a bunch of times: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892729/mongodb-vs-cassandra or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478916/what-should-i-choose-mongodb-cassandra-redis-couchdb

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably one of the best source which summarizes basic information (and points you to more detailed source in the first place) about various nosql databases is [this](http://nosql-databases.org/) website. Other than that you should check out these:

- [Cassandra vs MongoDB vs CouchDB vs Redis vs Riak vs HBase comparison](http://kkovacs.eu/cassandra-vs-mongodb-vs-couchdb-vs-redis)
- [Redis Memory Usage](http://nosql.mypopescu.com/post/1010844204/redis-memory-usage)
- [What The Heck Are You Actually Using NoSQL For?](http://highscalability.com/blog/2010/12/6/what-the-heck-are-you-actually-using-nosql-for.html)
- [NoSQLDatabases.com](http://www.nosqldatabases.com/)

Comment: Thanks! I like the first link in particular.