# query XML/JSON collection like a relational database?

Tags: sql, xml, database, json, api

i saved 10.000 api call answers in a plain txt file. there are 100s of most things have most set..

how to simply automatically import it into a database and make various queries efficiently?

-sample data: http://pastebin.com/C5yjSjCf

-scheme: http://awis.amazonaws.com/AWSAlexa/AWSAlexa.xsd )

thanks

Answer (score 1):

I can think of two solutions,

1. Use one of the many NoSQL DB, check [this out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5520620/quick-reference-guide-to-various-nosql-databases), mongoDB looks like a good choice
2. Use unix commands to query the file

Comment: 1. thank you. i know that NoSQL databases use XML/Json but thougth some of the content structure here may be too individual and will possibly be totally missunderstood or at least require manual corrections after the import? Whats, the solution that will require the least manual work?

Comment: (2. would try with many piped grep / sed commands but may get stuck for some of the queries/will require much more thought than SQL like queries)

Comment: (3. xquery is very slow
 4. individual import script very tedious)