# Basic Concepts comparison between Cassandra and MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, cassandra

All:

I am pretty new to NoSQL. I read some of docs from cassandra and mongoDB, but this make me feel more confused, could someone give some comparison(or list) about the  similar fundamental terminology(concept) in them side by side?

Right now the first thing confused me is:

Keyspace,  columns families, Row in Cassandra

VS

db, collections, document in MongoDB

Thanks

Comment: http://www.planetcassandra.org/mysql-to-cassandra-migration/#Key_Terminology and for mongodb http://www.linuxjournal.com/files/linuxjournal.com/ufiles/imagecache/medium-350px-centered/u1002061/11569f1.jpg

Comment: @Sammaye  Thanks, now I get it.

Answer (score 0):

No reason to re-invent the wheel!

Read these posts:

[MongoDB vs. Cassandra](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2892729/mongodb-vs-cassandra)

[What should I choose: MongoDB/Cassandra/Redis/CouchDB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3478916/what-should-i-choose-mongodb-cassandra-redis-couchdb)

You can also search youtube to find some answer on the technology.  For example, for cassandra you could view:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RMSNLP_ORg8

Comment: If you read past the title he isn't actually asking for that. He is asking for reference in terminology. Instead you have writtten a "vs" answer

Comment: I saw this post sitting here without an answer for 2 hours, and only had time to make a quick reply.  Feel free to compile an exhaustive list and provide a detailed answer.

Comment: @ChrisGerlt Thanks, actually what I want is just a concept comparison, I am not sure which concept in MongoDB according to which in Cassandra, no need for a full list, just for concepts I list above